# How i can make light for torch for player in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

how i can make **AREA** torch for player in Unity?

I try set for torch: a spot, area, point

Spot light in one side, but me need in area.
Area light don't working.
point light work, but in one position in other low light

I try search in youtube and google on Russian and English language, but everyone tell about flashlight or other.

I use: Render Path: Legacy Vertex Lit.

Comment: It is sure that you need spot light. You need to adjust settings.

Comment: Torch as in a flashlight or a burning stick?